# Dictionary (key , value) order

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Assume i have the following code

```
var dictionary = ["cat": 2,"dog":4,"snake":8]; // mutable dictionary
var keys  = dictionary.keys
var values = dictionary.values
for e in keys {
    println(e)
}
for v in values {
    println(v)
}
```

would the dictionary.keys and dictionary.values have the same order

for example if the dictionary.keys is "dog","snake","cat"
would the dictionary.values be always 4,8,2?
i tried it on the playground and the result always indicated that they have the same order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not guaranteed to be in the same order. From documentation:

> Swift’s Dictionary type is an unordered collection. The order in which
>   keys, values, and key-value pairs are retrieved when iterating over a
>   dictionary is not specified.

Comment: This is true. Although experience suggests that they appear in the same order for simple tests there is no guarantee for it. If you need a certain order use a separate array for the keys.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the `keys` and `values` property is preceded by the following
comments:

```
/// A collection containing just the keys of `self`
///
/// Keys appear in the same order as they occur as the `.0` member
/// of key-value pairs in `self`.  Each key in the result has a
/// unique value.
var keys: LazyBidirectionalCollection<MapCollectionView<[Key : Value], Key>> { get }

/// A collection containing just the values of `self`
///
/// Values appear in the same order as they occur as the `.1` member
/// of key-value pairs in `self`.
var values: LazyBidirectionalCollection<MapCollectionView<[Key : Value], Value>> { get }
```

My interpretation of

> Keys/Values **appear in the same order** as they occur as the `.0`/`.1` member of
>   key-value pairs in `self`.

is that `dictionary.keys` and `dictionary.values` return the keys and values in
"matching" order.

So the key-value pairs of a dictionary do not have a specified order, but
the first, second, ... element of `dictionary.values`
is the dictionary value corresponding to the first, second, ... element of `dictionary.keys`.