# What is the purpose of a DictionaryIndex in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Per the header documentation on `Dictionary` in Swift:

> A hash-based mapping from `Key` to `Value` instances.  Also a
>   collection of key-value pairs with no defined ordering.

Note in particular- `no defined ordering`.

With this in mind, I'm having trouble fully understanding these computed variables (and the related methods that take these types):

```
// The position of the first element in a non-empty dictionary.  
var startIndex: DictionaryIndex<Key, Value> { get }

// The collection's "past the end" position.
var endIndex: DictionaryIndex<Key, Value> { get }
```

The "index" here is a `DictionaryIndex`.

However, the documentation on `DictionaryIndex` is kinda circular here:

> Used to access the key-value pairs in an instance of
>   `Dictionary<Key, Value>`.

What actually is the purpose of `DictionaryIndex`?

Comment: I'm not sure, however "no defined ordering" does not mean random ordering. `NSDictionary` does have a defined order for the keys, it's just that Apple doesn't document what it is and it's subject to change in future. Keys are sorted in whatever order will make dictionary access the fastest (or in the case of NSMutableDictionary, make modifying the dictionary the fastest).

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, you make an interesting point. I could see how ordering by hash would make a binary search look up possible, for example. Maybe some other magic behind the scenes is actually happening? Still not sure about DictionaryIndex, but thanks for the input! :)

Comment: You *can* subscript a dictionary with a DictionaryIndex (I think that is what Amit89 meant in the answer which was deleted just now). Example: `if let index = d.indexForKey("key") { let (k, v) = d[index] ; println((k, v)) }`.

Comment: Slightly related question on the order of keys and values  (with two opposite answers :) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353434/dictionary-key-value-order.

Answer (score 2):

We know that a `Dictionary` is composed of *keys and values*. Every **key** is mapped to a **value** *based* on some internal calculations. Here the mechanism used for this purpose is **Hashing**.

**From wikipedia:**

> A hash table uses a hash function to compute an index into an array of buckets or slots, from which the correct value can be found.

Consider that a `Dictionary` is a Hash Table, which uses some hash function and returns an object of type `DictionaryIndex` - using which you can access particular object directly in the Dictionary.

Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: I think you mean, "every key is mapped to an **index** based on some internal calculations," correct?

Comment: Yeah, I think I get what you mean-- along with the comment from @AbhiBeckert, I think this is how it works: `DictionaryIndex` represents the underlying index for a given key in the `Dictionary`. This allows binary look ups and other tricks, perhaps? :)

Comment: Nopes. A key is always mapped to a value in Dictionary based on some hash value (here it is `DictionaryIndex`).

Comment: Yup I agree to your last comment. This is what I think might be happening underground.

Comment: Ah, yeah, "keys are mapped to values"--> hence, a dictionary. ;) I meant, "keys are backed by an index for internal ordering purposes." In this case, the "index" involves a hash... which brings back the original question, though... why is a `DictionaryIndex` even needed if keys can just be ordered by hash alone?

Comment: I think apple has provided `DictionaryIndex` just for the easiness of developer, so you can play around with Dictionary items. You can access their order :) If you have used `Objective c's NSDictionary`, there is no such thing as index there. Items are accessed randomly, while case is bit different in `Swift's Dictionary`.

Comment: I imagine that internal implementation is close to what is described in the answer / comments. Just my 2 cents: `DictionaryIndex` exists because `Dictionary` conforms to the `CollectionType` protocol which defines it. Also there are no binary lookups. All `Dictionary` operations run in `O(1)` (except when it is internally bridged to `NSDictionary`)

Comment: Also generating a hash from a key is slow depending on what type of object the key is (you can use your own classes as keys). So if you're going to access a dictionary repeatedly in a tight loop then saving the DictionaryIndex is almost certainly going to improve performance and reduce battery consumption. It's also possible for two keys used in the same dictionary to have a "hash collision" which will destroy performance. If the keys are provided by end users, then you need to worry about denial of service attacks.