# Getting elements from array of dictionary and save the keys as string, and values as string

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries of type `<Int,String>` like this:

```
[14: "2", 17: "5", 6: "5", 12: "Ali", 11: "0", 2: "4", 5: "It it it", 15: "5", 18: "2", 16: "5", 8: "2", 13: "4", 19: "4", 1: "2", 4: "12-09-2017 - 9:52"]
```

I need to get the keys alone and save them in a string, and the values alone and save them in another string.

The results should look like that:

```
string key = "12,17,6,12,11,2,5,15,18,16,8,13,19,1,4"
string values = "2,5,5,Ali,0,4,It it ti,5,2,5,2,4,4,2,12-09-2017 - 9:52"
```

Comment: That's not an array of dictionaries. That just a single dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary has a `keys` and a `values` property which return the
keys/values as a (lazy) collection. For the values you just have 
to join them:

```
let dict = [14: "2", 17: "5", 6: "5", 12: "Ali", 11: "0", 2: "4", 5: "It it it", 15: "5", 18: "2", 16: "5", 8: "2", 13: "4", 19: "4", 1: "2", 4: "12-09-2017 - 9:52"]

let values = dict.values.joined(separator: ",")
// Ali,5,2,It it it,5,0,4,5,4,4,2,12-09-2017 - 9:52,5,2,2
```

The keys are integers and must be converted to strings first:

```
let keys = dict.keys.map(String.init).joined(separator: ",")
// 12,17,14,5,15,11,13,16,19,2,18,4,6,8,1
```

The order is unspecified, but the same for keys and values.

Comment: I was just about to post the same code. I was actually surprised the order of the keys and values match each other. Since a dictionary has no order, I would have guessed that the order of `dict.value` might be different than the order of `dict.keys` but they are the same within a given execution.

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, the documentation states that *"When iterated over, keys  appear in this collection in the same order as they occur in the dictionary’s key-value pairs."* and the same for the values, so they match as long as the dictionary is not modified. – At least that is my interpretation, this was also discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353434/dictionary-key-value-order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this can be refactored I am sure, this is the first logic that hit me.

```
let dictionary = [14: "2", 17: "5", 6: "5", 12: "Ali", 11: "0", 2: "4", 5: "It it it", 15: "5", 18: "2", 16: "5", 8: "2", 13: "4", 19: "4", 1: "2", 4: "12-09-2017 - 9:52"]


let arrayKeys = dictionary.map({ $0.key})
print(arrayKeys)

var stringValue: String = ""

for value in arrayKeys {
    stringValue.append(value.description)
    stringValue.append(",")
}
```

Comment: why you get `arrayKeys` by `map`ing all keys in dictionary? there is `dictionary.keys` that do exactly what you want.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thanks @pacification